# We have 2 variants of device which differ only by battery. Shall we pass FCC separate FCC certification for every of them?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, fcc

We developed a BT4LE device which is being shipped in two variants. They are the same except for battery variant.

Is it possible for us to pass one FCC certification so that it is valid for both device variants? Are there any items to be careful about?

Comment: If you asked an FCC engineer, what questions do you think they would ask in order to come to an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This falls under the topic of "permissive changes".   The FCC has a document called [PERMISSIVE CHANGE POLICY](https://apps.fcc.gov/kdb/GetAttachment.html?id=2WVe%2FJ0PoOiHR8I6M85rGg%3D%3D&desc=178919%20D01%20Permissive%20Change%20Policy%20v05r04&tracking_number=33013) which outlines what can or cannot be changed without requiring a new FCC ID.

Under section 2 c). it says, "Part substitution – electrically identical parts may be substituted."

I would assume that the two batteries are the same voltage, but perhaps different capacities (mAh) or chemistries?  For example, allowing for either rechargeable or non-rechargeable batteries in the same package (such as two AA's) shouldn't be a problem.  However if the two battery variants are substantially different in size, it could be argued that would affect the RF performance of the device (since they have a metal casing) and require re-testing.

Your RF testing house may be able to give you some guidance on whether different size batteries would affect the results.

Comment: Ah, bureaucracy